# Font Name support character set 864

Tags: character, arabic

I want to know the font name which support character set 864 / 1256 for Arabic Printing.

I am using it for POS with 4610-tf6 printer.

Comment: try `Amiri` font: http://www.amirifont.org/

Comment: is it support arabic and english??

Comment: no this not work... showing character set 101